# C structure dereference chain efficiency

Tags: c

This one is about dereferencing stucture variables in a chain. Please consider this code:

```
struct ChannelInfo
{
    int iData1;
    int iData2;
    int iData3;
    int iData4;
}

struct AppInfo
{
    struct ChannelInfo gChanInfo[100];

} gAppInfo;


void main()
{

    gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData1 = 1;
    gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData2 = 2;
    gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData3 = 3;
    gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData4 = 4;
    foo1();
    foo2();
}

void foo1()
{
    printf("Data1 = %d, Data2 = %d, Data3 = %d, Data4 = %d", gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData1, gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData2, gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData3, gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData4);
}

void foo2()
{
    struct ChannelInfo* pCurrrentChan = &gAppInfo.gChanInfo[50];
    printf("Data1 = %d, Data2 = %d, Data3 = %d, Data4 = %d", pCurrrentChan->iData1, pCurrrentChan->iData2, pCurrrentChan->iData3, pCurrrentChan->iData4);
}
```

Is foo2() any faster than foo1()? What happens if the array index was not a constant, being asked for by the user? I would be grateful if someone could profile this code.

Comment: Have you tried any benchmark?

Comment: ok, you have already nice answers @samofoz

Comment: There's rarely any direct relation between the amount of source code written and program efficiency...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pondering things like this isn't meaningful and it is pre-mature optimization, because the code will get optimized so that both those functions are equivalent.

If you for some reason would not optimize the code, foo2() will be slightly slower because it yields a few more instructions.

Please not that the call to printf is approximately 100 times slower than the rest of the code in that function, so if you are truly concerned about performance you should rather focus on avoiding stdio.h instead of doing these kinds of mini-optimizations.

At the bottom of the answer I have included some benchmarking code for Windows. Because the printf call is so slow compared to the rest of the code, and we aren't really interested in benchmarking printf itself, I removed the printf calls and replaced them with volatile variables. Meaning that the compiler is required to perform the reads no matter level of optimization.

> gcc test.c -otest.exe -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -O0

Output:

```
foo1 5.669101us
foo2 7.178366us
```

> gcc test.c -otest.exe -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -O2

Output:

```
foo1 2.509606us
foo2 2.506889us
```

As we can see, the difference in execution time of the non-optimized code corresponds roughly to the number of assembler instructions produced (see the answer by @dvhh).

Unscientifically:

10 / (10 + 16) instructions = 0.384

5.67 / (5.67 + 7.18) microseconds = 0.441

---

Benchmarking code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


struct ChannelInfo
{
  int iData1;
  int iData2;
  int iData3;
  int iData4;
};

struct AppInfo
{
  struct ChannelInfo gChannelInfo[100];

} gAppInfo;


void foo1 (void);
void foo2 (void);

static double get_time_diff_us (const LARGE_INTEGER* freq, 
                                const LARGE_INTEGER* before, 
                                const LARGE_INTEGER* after)
{
  return ((after->QuadPart - before->QuadPart)*1000.0) / (double)freq->QuadPart;
}


int main (void)
{
  /*** Initialize benchmarking functions ***/
  LARGE_INTEGER freq;
  if(QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq)==FALSE)
  {
    printf("QueryPerformanceFrequency not supported");
    return 0;
  }

  LARGE_INTEGER time_before;
  LARGE_INTEGER time_after;

  gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData1 = 1;
  gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData2 = 2;
  gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData3 = 3;
  gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData4 = 4;


  const size_t ITERATIONS = 1000000;

  QueryPerformanceCounter(&time_before);
  for(size_t i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++)
  {
    foo1();
  }
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&time_after);
  printf("foo1 %fus\n", get_time_diff_us(&freq, &time_before, &time_after));

  QueryPerformanceCounter(&time_before);
  for(size_t i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++)
  {
    foo2();
  }
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&time_after);
  printf("foo2 %fus\n", get_time_diff_us(&freq, &time_before, &time_after));

}


void foo1 (void)
{
  volatile int d1, d2, d3, d4;

  d1 = gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData1;
  d2 = gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData2;
  d3 = gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData3;
  d4 = gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50].iData4;
}

void foo2 (void)
{
  struct ChannelInfo* pCurrrentChan = &gAppInfo.gChannelInfo[50];
  volatile int d1, d2, d3, d4;

  d1 = pCurrrentChan->iData1;
  d2 = pCurrrentChan->iData2;
  d3 = pCurrrentChan->iData3;
  d4 = pCurrrentChan->iData4;
}
```

Comment: On a Sleep(1), this method is printing 1.xxxxxx. Wondering if the function should be named get_time_diff_ms()?

Comment: @samofoz Possibly, the multiplication should be with `1000000.0`. Still, attempting to benchmark anything in Windows always gives questionable results. How long is a `Sleep(1)`? Nobody knows, since you yield your process' time slice to the OS when doing so. For this specific case, only the execution time difference between the two functions matters anyway.

Comment: You're right, we dont know how much a Sleep(1) takes. I tried another machine and the method returns the number 15.xxxxxx for about 100 interations. Can you please confirm if this profiling method indeed prints ns? I feel a bit confused.

Comment: Edit: It returned 0.x, 1.x, 2.x a few times on a million iterations.

Comment: @samofoz Microsoft claims it should be 1000000 as in nanoseconds, though I don't quite get that to sync with the real world results. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Sounds quite fishy to measure things with nanosecond resolution though.

Answer (score 4):

this [assembly version of your code](https://goo.gl/xhL1rk) could help you understand why your code is slower. But of course it could vary depending on the target architecture and you optimization flags ( Commpiling with `O2` or `O3` flags produce the same code for `foo1` and `foo2` )

In `foo2` the address of `ChannelInfo` is stored in a register and address are calculated relative to the value stored in the register. Or in the worst case in the stack (local variable ) where in that case it could be as slow as `foo1`.

In `foo1` the variable address for printf are calculated relative to the variable `gAppInfo` stored in memory heap (or in cache ).

As per @Ludin's request I added [these numbers for reference](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) :

- Execution of an instruction : 1 ns
- fetch from main memory : ~100 ns

[assembly version with -O2 flags](https://goo.gl/kl8ywd) ( -Os and -O3 flags produce the same code )

Comment: 16 assembler instructions is faster than 10 now? I don't know how many cpu ticks each of these op codes take, but spontaneously it would seem you just proved that foo1 is faster, which contradicts the text in your answer. Indirect access is often slightly slower than direct. For completeness, could you per chance include the assembly output for compiling with all optimizations enabled? Which is the important lesson here: avoid pre-mature optimization and write readable code instead.

Comment: The optimized code looks nearly identical to the non-optimized foo1. So apparently the compiler doesn't think that accessing that struct with relative addresses is time consuming at all, likely because accessing that variable does not take any overhead time.

Comment: Posted some benchmarking code to prove that the non-optimized foo1() is indeed faster.

Answer (score 1):

yes, foo2() is definitely faster than foo1() because foo2 refers a pointer to that memory block and everytime you access it just points there and fetches value from the mmory.

Comment: The output in dvhh's answer just proved the opposite, for a given CPU. But that's with optimizations disabled. With optimizations enabled there should be no difference.

Comment: that might be true but working with pointers makes fetching the data faster.

Comment: No. You cannot just generically say "pointers are faster", where did you get that strange idea from? The assembly already proved you wrong, but if that's not enough I also posted some benchmarking code for a PC. See for yourself.